# Why is there massive white space under my image in React? What's creating this mysterious div?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm building a login Component in React, and trying to add the brand image. When I do this, I'm getting a **huge** amount of white space underneath it.

I've been working on this for a bit now, and I've discovered that, when I look in the dev tools, I can make headway by modifying this mysterious div that seems to be created by [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com), the front-end framework I'm using.

[image: Screenshot of the div, and the impact on the layout from modifying padding-top.]

When I look into this in the dev tools, I find that there's a div with the attribute `padding-top: calc(100%)` which, when modified to something like `padding-top: calc(30%)`, reduces the size of this whitespace underneath the image.

I've also tried some of the basic layout solutions suggested in many of the answers to similar questions here on SO, but none of them make a difference. It seems that this padding issue is at the heart of the problem.

#### The Problem

Because I don't know what's creating this div, I'm not able to override the padding to work towards a solution. I've tried modifying `paddingTop` and `padding` with the `!important` tag in the styling of both the image, and the parent element of the image.

**Code Sample**

```
          <Paper variant='outlined' style={{ width: '380px' }}>
            <Box m={4}>
              <Image 
                src='../static/images/TextLogo.svg' 
                imageStyle={{
                  height: 'auto',
                  width: '100%',
                }}  
              />
            </Box>
          ...
```

#### Stack

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0-alpha.8",
"material-ui-image": "^3.2.3",
"next": "^8.1.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6"
```

Thanks. I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: This is coming from your `Image` component: https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-image/blob/v3.2.3/src/components/Image/Image.js#L57

Comment: Awesome, Ryan. You got it. If you submit as an answer, it would be my pleasure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div>` with the `padding-top` and other styles is coming from the `Image` component that you are using from `material-ui-image`.

Below is the overall structure [rendered by that `Image` component](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-image/blob/v3.2.3/src/components/Image/Image.js#L122):

```
      <div
        style={styles.root}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        {image.src && <img
          {...image}
          style={styles.image}
          onLoad={this.handleLoadImage}
          onError={this.handleImageError}
        />}
        <div style={styles.iconContainer}>
          {!disableSpinner && !this.state.imageLoaded && !this.state.imageError && loading}
          {!disableError && this.state.imageError && errorIcon}
        </div>
      </div>
```

`padding-top` is part of the styles in `styles.root`.

[**styles.root**](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-image/blob/v3.2.3/src/components/Image/Image.js#L57):

```
    const styles = {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: color,
        paddingTop: `calc(1 / ${aspectRatio} * 100%)`,
        position: 'relative',
        ...style
      },
```

When `padding-top` is a percentage, it is a [percentage of the width](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/#article-header-id-3), so it is important to control the width of the container in order to have predictable behavior.

You can modify the `padding-top` by either explicitly overriding it via the `style` prop or by specifying the appropriate value in the `aspectRatio` prop. By default, this Image component is assuming square images (`aspectRatio: 1`).

Here is a working example demonstrating both ways of controlling `padding-top`:

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "material-ui-image";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box m={4} width={200}>
        <Image
          aspectRatio={1.5}
          src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/velka/black-monkey-11280155875i3QV.jpg"
        />
        Something under image 1
      </Box>
      <Box m={4} width={200}>
        <Image
          style={{
            paddingTop: "calc(66.7%)"
          }}
          src="https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/velka/black-monkey-11280155875i3QV.jpg"
        />
        Something under image 2
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit material-ui-image]

Slightly related answer (with regard to the use of `padding-top`): [A good way to handle @material-ui Skeleton scaling within a variable height grid row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461615/a-good-way-to-handle-material-ui-skeleton-scaling-within-a-variable-height-grid/59462150#59462150)